# Can an NFT be minted with shareholding on two different addresses?

Tags: nft

Like ownership of the NFT is divided and owned by two different addresses?
like 50% owned by Address 1 and 50% owned by Address 2.

Comment: You could have a multi-signature wallet that is controlled by 2 persons and the owner of that NFT will be the address of the mutli signature wallet.

Comment: Theoretically, everything is simple - you use a smart contract for an NFT token that supports shared ownership. But if you want your NFT token to be traded in a similar way on some NFT token exchange, then you need to look specifically at the set of token standards that this exchange supports.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the comments, the answer seems to be no. Even a multi-sig wallet is only 1 address, not two.

**Fractionalization** of NFTs is becoming more common and is another way to share ownership of the same NFT though. Units of custom ERC-20 tokens representing ownership of the fractionalized NFT are possessed by each fractional owner in their wallet. The whole NFT does not exist in the fractional owners' multiple wallets.